# Why is only one character being changed correctly?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

My code is as follows:

```
import msvcrt
userKeyPress = [""]
x = 0
whereInList = 0
def writeToList(char):
    if " " not in char:

        userKeyPress[whereInList] = userKeyPress[whereInList] + char

while x == 0:
    userChar = msvcrt.getch()
    userChar = userChar.decode("ASCII")
    if " " in userChar:
        whereInList = whereInList + 1
        userKeyPress.extend(" ")
    elif " " not in userChar and "q" not in userChar:
        writeToList(userChar)
    elif "q" in userChar:
        print(userKeyPress)
        x = 1
```

It takes the user input and puts it in a list, with spaces creating a new list value. When ran it is able to convert the first letter the user presses from the byte string format but all other characters are not as the first one is.

For example, if I type the letters on my keyboard "a" then "b" then "c" it returns

```
['a\x00b\x00c\x00']
```

The first letter is fine, but the two after have \x00 before them. Why is this, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: In fact, each of all the three letters has a NULL-terminator (`\x00`) _after_ it. You can just slice it away if you want.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks very much! If you want to make that a full answer I'll mark it as the answer for you. (As in not a comment)

Comment: @ForceBru: is that a side effect of `msvcrt.getch()`? It doesn't seem to be mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/msvcrt.html).

Comment: I don't get why there would be a null terminator here, but I don't use Windows much. The docs says that `getch` should deal with ascii characters. You could try to use `msvcrt.getwch()` instead. That should return a unicode character, and the decoding step is presumably not needed.

Comment: @usr2564301, I'm not really sure, but I think it's just returning C-strings, which are NULL-terminated. This may be incorrect, though, because if I were to develop this function, I'd just return raw integers (as returned by `ord`) or single characters, so it doesn't make much sense to me to return C-strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are converting UTF-16 encoded characters to ASCII. 
UTF-16 is the default encoding in Windows, and represents all characters in two bytes, which means that all characters in the ascii set will include a null byte `\x00`.

Reading to the docs, I would expect `msvcrt.getch()` to return ASCII encoded characters, so this is unexpected.

In any case, if you replace `decode("ASCII")` with `decode('utf16')`, you should get the expected output.

Comment: Unexpected, yes. The documentation reads like it should use the thread's current "ANSI code page" to me. Could be tested by typing (or piping) test characters such as €  and .

Comment: Windows still uses ANSI code pages? I don't have a Windows computer at hand to test this, but if someone can try this out, feel free to edit my answer to add more information. The docs also recommend using `msvcrt.getwch()`, which should return the characters as properly decoded unicode strings.